# AngularJs routing issue using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ngroute

My AngularJs routing always redirects to the home page and always calls `HomeController` rather than redirecting to `/VechileRegistration/Index`, `VechileRegistration/VechileInward`

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'HomeController',
    templateUrl: '/home/home.view.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .when('/VechileRegistration/Index', {
    controller: 'HomeController2',
    templateUrl: '/home/home.view2.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .when('/VechileRegistration/VechileInward', {
    controller: 'VehicleInwardController',
    templateUrl: '/home/VehicleInward.view.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
  });
```

How can I redirect to the right place and call the appropriate controller?

Comment: On the surface things look right. You are injecting `ngRoute` in your app and you have referenced the appropriate `angular-route.js` file? That is, it's the same version as the main `angular.js` file you're using?

Comment: This might be just typos, but your paths are "vechile" while you and your users may be typing in the URL "vehicle" (to match your controller names).   Just want to double check the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var app = angular.module('ngRoutingDemo', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
         
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        }).when('/student/:username', {
            templateUrl: '/student.html',
            controller: 'studentController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });

    app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $location) {
       
        $scope.authenticate = function (username) {
            // write authentication code here.. 

            $location.path('/student/' + username)
        };

    });

    app.controller("studentController", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
    });

});
```

Comment: Worth adding in information as to why this answers the OP question.